# Replicating azure websites across different availability zones (file system)

Tags: azure

We are currently running an Azure website within the West Europe region. Ideally we would like to create a copy running in a different region to fall back to in case the current region goes down. Is there a simple way to enable replication of the site data built into Azure (or a known service, code etc.)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman just blogged about exactly this.  You can find it on his blog here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CloudPowerHowToScaleAzureWebsitesGloballyWithTrafficManager.aspx

Comment: This looks good, however the files won't be synced accross the different sites (I'm using Umbraco and it has local configs, lucene indeces etc. that change when content is published) These are all local to the file system which is the problem

Comment: Umbraco can be setup to work in a non-fileshare environment.  You have unique search indeces but it works.  Your best bet would be to run Umbraco on VMs.